# add_query_arg() for custom post type on all visible links

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I am trying to add add_query_art() $GET['var'] to auto filled form field.

I have custom post type call career and want to auto filled field for the Position so url I want is http://mydomain.com/career/opening-position/?position=positionname

I am getting above url from loop as I have manually added using add_query_arg() but now I want it to apply everywhere where the link appear on the site. Like widget etc..

I modify the_permalink using filter and it is working but the problem is it apply add_query_arg() return value to all permalink if I am on the career page.

Here is my filter code

```
// permalink filter to add get var
function append_query_string($url) {

    if('career' == get_post_type()){

        global $career_mb;
        $career = $career_mb->the_meta();

        return add_query_arg('position', $career['career_position'], $url);

    } else {

      return add_query_arg($_GET, $url);  

    }
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
```

Hope I wrote clear to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `post_type_link` instead. This is reserved for custom post types, and you get the `post` object, so you don’t need a global variable for this.

```
is_admin() or add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'career_position_url', 10, 2 );

function career_position_url( $url, $post )
{
    global $career_mb;

    if ( 'career' !== $post->post_type )
        return $url;

    $career = $career_mb->the_meta();

    return add_query_arg( 'position', $career['career_position'], $url );
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! didn't know that.. you saved me..